# Remote login through ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote-access, openssh

Let A and B are two computers on different network. A and B knows their public and private Ip.
How B should have SSH log in to A. I don't want port forwarding and reverse ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the two "external" Ip's, you can do a tunnel between servers A and B with  [bidireccional tunnel](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).